# XSLT Transformation can't get right number of Tags/Nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT and XML and I cannot get the transformation right.  Using examples off the net I either end up missing tags or nodes (I'm not sure of the terminology) or they are duplicated.  Below are samples of the input and desired output.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2016-11-04T15:53:41">
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
<KpiId>122</KpiId>
<Value>4418.88</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
<KpiId>121</KpiId>
<Value>44.35</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Whitby</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
<KpiId>121</KpiId>
<Value>46.75</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
</dataroot>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ActualKPIDayImport> 
  <ActualKPIDay>
    <XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
    <DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
    <KpiId>122</KpiId>
    <Value>4418.88</Value>
  </ActualKPIDay>
  <ActualKPIDay>
    <XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
    <DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
    <KpiId>121</KpiId>
    <Value>44.35</Value>
  </ActualKPIDay>
  <ActualKPIDay>
    <XrefCode>Whitby</XrefCode>
    <DayId>2016-11-03</DayId>
    <KpiId>121</KpiId>
    <Value>46.75</Value>
  </ActualKPIDay>
</ActualKPIDayImport>
```

My most recent attempt resulted in leaving the "dataroot" line and duplicating the "ActualKPIDay" tag before and after each record:

Code attempt:

```
xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dataroot">
  <xsl:copy>
   <ActualKPIDayImport>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </ActualKPIDayImport>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ActualKPIDay">
  <ActualKPIDay>
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </ActualKPIDay>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<ActualKPIDayImport>
<ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03T00:00:00</DayId>
<KpiId>122</KpiId>
<Value>4418.88</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
</ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Etobicoke</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03T00:00:00</DayId>
<KpiId>121</KpiId>
<Value>44.35</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
</ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<ActualKPIDay>
<XrefCode>Georgetown</XrefCode>
<DayId>2016-11-03T00:00:00</DayId>
<KpiId>121</KpiId>
<Value>425.29</Value>
</ActualKPIDay>
</ActualKPIDay>
</ActualKPIDayImport>
</dataroot>
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the last template and take out the `<xsl:copy>` tags of the dataroot template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dataroot" priority="1">  
   <ActualKPIDayImport>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </ActualKPIDayImport>  
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" priority="2">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @GregK - see updated XSLT to strip out namespaces in output.

Comment: I don't profess to understand the code, but worked like a charm.

Comment: Great! Basically the first template, based on identity template extracts only local-name of the node leaving out special namespaces. The last template returns only text values from nodes with text values.